# Position widget full width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Positioned widget that I need to make it full width of the parent container

Widget tree is like this

```
Expanded
  Stack
    SomeOtherWidgets
    Positioned(
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      height: 11,
      child: Container(
        // box decoration for this container
      )
    )
```

So what I need is a widget placed at the bottom of the Stack that goes on top of everything else in the Stack, that takes up the width of the ancestor Expanded

Is this possible? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use `Positioned.fill()`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to set left and right to 0, so it will expand full width.

If you want to expand a Positioned widget height and width, you can use Positioned.fill() which will set left/right/top/bottom to 0. (but you can override them if needed)

Answer (score 2):

So here's a full working implementation. It's based on the top comment idea. I am using it and it works as a charm.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PaddedGestureDetector extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double padding;
  final bool debug;

  final GestureTapCallback? onTap;
  final GestureTapDownCallback? onTapDown;
  final GestureTapUpCallback? onTapUp;
  final GestureTapCancelCallback? onTapCancel;

  final GestureDoubleTapCallback? onDoubleTap;

  final GestureLongPressCallback? onLongPress;
  final GestureLongPressUpCallback? onLongPressUp;
  final GestureLongPressStartCallback? onLongPressStart;
  final GestureLongPressEndCallback? onLongPressEnd;
  final GestureLongPressMoveUpdateCallback? onLongPressMoveUpdate;

  final GestureTapDownCallback? onSecondaryTapDown;
  final GestureTapUpCallback? onSecondaryTapUp;
  final GestureTapCancelCallback? onSecondaryTapCancel;
  final GestureTapCallback? onSecondaryTap;

  const PaddedGestureDetector({
    Key? key,
    required this.padding,
    this.debug = false,
    this.onTap,
    this.onTapDown,
    this.onTapUp,
    this.onTapCancel,
    this.onDoubleTap,
    this.onLongPress,
    this.onLongPressUp,
    this.onLongPressStart,
    this.onLongPressEnd,
    this.onLongPressMoveUpdate,
    this.onSecondaryTapDown,
    this.onSecondaryTapUp,
    this.onSecondaryTapCancel,
    this.onSecondaryTap,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        child,
        Positioned(
          top: -padding,
          left: -padding,
          right: -padding,
          bottom: -padding,
          child: GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              onTap: onTap,
              onTapDown: onTapDown,
              onTapUp: onTapUp,
              onTapCancel: onTapCancel,
              onDoubleTap: onDoubleTap,
              onLongPress: onLongPress,
              onLongPressUp: onLongPressUp,
              onLongPressStart: onLongPressStart,
              onLongPressEnd: onLongPressEnd,
              onLongPressMoveUpdate: onLongPressMoveUpdate,
              onSecondaryTapDown: onSecondaryTapDown,
              onSecondaryTapUp: onSecondaryTapUp,
              onSecondaryTapCancel: onSecondaryTapCancel,
              onSecondaryTap: onSecondaryTap,
              child: debug
                  ? Opacity(
                      opacity: 0.4,
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.pink[((Random().nextInt(4) + 4) * 100)],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                      )),
                    )
                  : Container()),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```